# The derivative of a map is Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

If $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a map of class $C^2$ defined on a compact $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with non-empty interior, is it true that the map $Df : U \rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ is Lipschitz? (Where, of course, $L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ is a normed vector space with the operator norm).

This seems a tricky question, because the *linear map* $Df(x)$ is, of course Lipschitz, but I don't know if this is true for the map above.

Comment: That's why the domain $U$ needs to be compact, I guess.

Comment: Oh I missed that $U$ is compact. Than yes

Comment: How is $Df, D^2f$ defined on non interior points of $U$?

Comment: @copper.hat usually by assuming that there's a function $g$ defined on an open set containing $U$ which is differentiable on $U$ and coincides with $f$ everywhere on $U$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1622593/27978.

Answer (score 0):

At least there is a simple proof if $U$ is also convex.

Hint:
$$ Df(x+h) - Df(x) = \int_0^1 Df^2(x+th)h dt. $$