# If $f$ is locally Lipschitz, then for any compact set $K$, $f \mid_K$ is globally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

This problem has been asked here before. For example, this question [Prove that the restriction $f|_K$ of $f$ to $K$ is globally Lipschitz where $K$ is a compact set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375714/prove-that-the-restriction-f-k-of-f-to-k-is-globally-lipschitz-where-k) only treated the continuity of $f$ on $K$ while this question [$f \in C^1$ defined on a compact set $K$ is Lipschitz?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622557/f-in-c1-defined-on-a-compact-set-k-is-lipschitz?noredirect=1&lq=1) already assumed $f$ to be $C^1$ function. Although, the latter was close to answering my question but used terms difficult for me to understand. So, in both cases, they have not answered my question. So, here it is

> If $f:O\subset \Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$ is locally Lipschitz, then prove that for any compact set $K$ in $O,$ $f \mid_K$ is Lipschitz such that $\exists \;c\in [x,y]$ such that \begin{align}\Vert f(x)-f(y) \Vert\leq c\Vert x-y \Vert,\;\;\forall\;x,y\in K\end{align}

**My efforts**

Let $K$ be compact in $O$. Let $x,y\in K$, then by MVT, $\exists \;r\in [x,y]$ such that \begin{align}\Vert f(x)-f(y) \Vert\leq \sup\limits_{r\in [x,y]}\Vert f'(r) \Vert\Vert x-y \Vert\end{align}
\begin{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad\leq \sup\limits_{r\in K}\Vert f'(r) \Vert\Vert x-y \Vert\end{align}
Since $f$ is locally Lipschitz, then it is continuous and since $K$ is compact, then the maximum is reached. So, let 
\begin{align}c= \sup\limits_{r\in K}\Vert f'(r) \Vert\end{align}
Thus, 
\begin{align}\Vert f(x)-f(y) \Vert\leq c\Vert x-y \Vert,\;\;\forall\;x,y\in K\end{align}

Please, can anyone help me check if my proof is correct? If no, alternative proofs will be highly regarded! Thanks!

Comment: Your proof works only when $f$ is $C^1$.

Comment: @Crostul: But $f$ Lipschitz doesn't imply $f$  is $C^1$

Comment: Well, the proof would work (since a Lipschitz function is ae. differentiable), but it needs a bit more finness & something like the Rademacher theorem.

Comment: The  incorrect assumption that $f$ must differentiable renders it invalid..... BTW "compact" is an intrinsic property of a space or sub-space. $K$ is compact in $O$ iff $K$ is compact in $\Bbb R^n$ iff $K$ is a compact sub$space$ of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [In $\Bbb R^n$
, locally Lipschitz on compact set implies Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/154721/721644)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I am not a fan of proof by contradiction, it works efficiently here.

Suppose $S(x,y)={\|f(x)-f(y)| \over \|x-y\|}$ is unbounded for $x,y \in K, x \neq y$. Then we can find $x_k, y_k \in K$ such that $S(x_k,y_k) \to \infty$. Since $K$ is compact,
we can assume that $x_k \to x, y_k \to y$. Since $f$ is bounded on $K$, we
must have $x=y$ (otherwise $S(x_k,y_k)$ would not be unbounded). By assumption, $f$ is locally Lipschitz around $x$, hence $S(x_k,y_k) \le L$ for some (finite) $L$, which is a contradiction.

---

Here is a constructive proof:

Since $f$ is locally Lipschitz, for each $x$ there is some $r_x>0$ and $L_x$ such that $f$ is Lipschitz with rank $L_x$ on $B(x,r_x)$.

Then the sets $B(x, {1 \over 2} r_x)$, $x \in O$ form an open cover of $K$, so
a finite number cover $K$. For convenience, denote these by $B(x_k, {1 \over 2} r_k)$ (instead of
$r_{x_k}$).

Let $M= \sup_{x \in M} \|f(x)\|$, $r= {1 \over 2}\min r_k$,  $L_0 = {2M \over r}$
and $L= \max (L_0, L_k)$. Then $L$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f$ on $K$.

To see this, pick $x,y \in K$. If $\|x-y\| \ge r$ then we see that ${ \|f(x)-f(y) \| \over \|x - y \|} \le {2M \over r} = L_0 \le L$. If $\|x-y\| < r$, then for some $x_k$ we have $x \in B(x_k, {1 \over 2} r_k)$. Then $y \in B(x_k, r_k)$ and
so $\|f(x)-f(y) \| \le L_k \|x - y \| \le L \|x - y \|$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof by contradiction. I'll go through the proof. Ask questions where needed and then, thick!

Comment: There is the "hidden", yet noteworthy, detail that $y_k\ne x_k$ for all $k$.

Comment: @Saucy O'Path: Thanks for the note!

Comment: There are many details omitted, ironically for clarity. Following Polonius, brevity is the soul of wit...

Comment: @copper.hat: Prof., I think you needed to consider subsequences, instead because of compactness! I may be wrong!

Comment: @Mike: You are correct, but we can always choose a subsequence and renumber. This is a fairly standard trick to reduce word count :-).

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks Prof.!

Comment: I added a tedious constructive proof.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks, I got that!

Comment: @copper.hat Excuse me, could you explain to me what you want mean when you say that $f$ is lischitz with rank $L_x$ on $B(x,r_x)$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: It means for all $a,b \in B(x,r_x)$ we have $\|f(a)-f(b)\| \le L_x \|a-b\|$.

Answer (score 1):

By our assumption, $\forall x \in O$, there is a open neighbourhood of $x$, $U_x$,  and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$||f(y) - f(z)|| \leq c_x ||y-z|| \quad \forall y,z \in U_x.$$

(Thanks to @copper.hat)

Let $K \subset O$ be compact, then it is the finite union of compact connected $J_ks $, and observe that $S = \{U_x\}_{x\in K}$ is an open cover for $K$, but since $K$ is compact, we can cover with a finite subset of $S$, namely $\{U_x\}_{x \in J}$ for some finite $J \subset K$.

Now, for each $k$, define

$$c_k = max\{c_x| x \in J_k\},$$
and 
$$c = max\{c_k\},$$
hence $f|_K$ is Lipschitz on $K$ with Lipschitz constant $c$.

Comment: This is not quite correct.

Comment: Take $f=0$ on $[0,1]$ and $f=1$ on $[2,3]$. Then $f$ is of local Lipschitz rank zero, but global rank one, hence taking the $\max$ is **not** sufficient. In addition, there is an implicit assumption in your proof that the domain is convex and can be joined by a straight line. It is straightforward to create an example (think horseshoe shape :-)) in which there is a small local rank but large global rank. A constructive proof requires a bit more work.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for pointing out. What if we assume that $K$ has finite compact connected components, and take the max. of each component ?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean when $K$ is compact, is there any chance of having infinitely many connected compact components ?

Comment: Sure, for example take a strictly decreasing, convergent sequence along with the limit. In any event, my example shows why the approach of taking the max fails.

Comment: @copper.hat I see, thanks for the response. I will edit correspond my answer according to even though you have already provided a constructive proof in your answer.

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote ?

Comment: Was not me. However, your answer is not correct. See the example in my second comment.

Comment: @copper.hat Then if I also take the maximum of $c_k$s with the distances between the connected component, then it should be correct, right ?

Comment: Well, the distances are not necessarily bounded away from zero, there may be an infinite number of components. For example, $K= \{ { 1 \over n } \}_n \cup \{0 \}$. You need to consider the slopes rather than the distances. It is a surprisingly subtle argument.

Comment: @copper.hat how such a space compact ? I mean for the cover $\{1/n\}\cap \{0\}$, i.e all the open sets in the space, I cannot think any finite subcover.

Comment: The set is closed and bounded. The open set that contains $0$ contains all but a finite number of the points.